# Filtering certain items from map - Java8 StreamAPI

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I've sorted a HashMap with following.

```
map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Collections.reverseOrder()))
            .skip(1)
            .limit(50)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (e1, e2) -> e1,
                    LinkedHashMap::new
            ));
```

What I want to do is filter some results from this, preferably using `.filter()`. Items that I want to filter are `ArrayList<String> filterUs;`

How can I do this?

---

Assume that I have following result after sort operation

```
{31795=11, 31790=11, 31876=10, 31803=9, 31792=8, 31877=8, 31851=8, 31845=8} 
filterUs = [31790,31876]
```

What I want to get: `{31795=11,  31803=9, 31792=8, 31877=8, 31851=8, 31845=8, newItem=7, anotherNewItem=6}`

Comment: a little bit unclear. filterUs contains *31790* and the result that you want to get contains that entry also: *31790=11*. is that a type somewhere? I think you meant: *filterUs=[31803,31876]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks funny, you put up a pretty complicated pipeline there and you can't do a filter? Unless I'm missing something it's pretty straightforward.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> result = map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Collections.reverseOrder()))
            .filter(entry -> !filterUs.contains(entry.getKey()))
            .skip(1)
            .limit(50)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
.filter(item -> item.getValue() instanceOf ArrayList)
```

to the stream.

The result will only contain entries that are `ArrayList`.  Invert the test (add a `!` after the `->`) if you want to remove those.

Comment: Thanks, but what I wanted to do is to remove is filter us, such that `{31795=11, 31790=11, 31876=10, 31803=9, 31792=8, 31877=8, 31851=8, 31845=8}` was original result, I wanna remove `filterUs = [31803,31876]`

Answer (score 0):

To use it, you would implement something along the lines of

```
map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Collections.reverseOrder()))
        .skip(1)
        .filter(entry -> item.getValue() instanceOf ArrayList) // <-- NEW
        .limit(50)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Map.Entry::getValue,
                (e1, e2) -> e1,
                LinkedHashMap::new
        ));
```

Comment: whoops. bad time to take a break from SO. sorry!